# Mockito: argThat for methods taking multiple arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito's argThat API:

```
verify(mockService).methodA(argThat((List ids, int b) -> ids.get(0).equals("123")));
```

mockService has `methodA` which takes two parameters: a List and a primitive integer.

But this gives me an error:

> "Imcompatible parameter types in lambda expression".

The reason is that ArgumentMatcher's matches method takes only one argument.

So how can I do verification for such scenarios?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use an `argThat` wildcard for each of the inputs:

```
verify(mockService).methodA(argThat((List ids) -> ids.get(0).equals("123"))
          , argThat((int b) -> b < 1);
```

I would also suggest you use `@ArgumentCaptor` which is an alternative to `argThat` and makes that custom matching a bit more clear: [javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html). Especially if you have to use both of the params at the same conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks for input. I had to change int to Integer to get it working.